# Why does Shopify App template not deploy to ECS correctly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ecs, shopify-app, shopify-template

I am trying to deploy my shopify app on ECS. I have deployed the container to a private ECR repository and now trying to get the app running on ECS. I have tried deploying without a Application Load Balancer (ALB) and it is deployed just fine, however, when I try to deploy the image with an ALB, it keeps failing health checks and deregistering the task from the target group in the alb. The container logs keep showing the error

`[shopify-app/ERROR] ensureInstalledOnShop did not receive a shop query argument | {shop: undefined}`

This error always shows in local development before I open the app on the test store. After I open the test store with the app it runs fine and the error doesnt show anymore.

So from all this I assume the issue lies with the setup of the load balancer or the app itself. For context, I created the app through the node.js app temnplate shopify provide through the cli, which runs an express app. Below is how Im setting up the load balancer when setting up the service:

[image: AWS Load Balancer Setup]

Keeping in mind I have exposed port 8081 on the container.

After everything sets up, this is the log from the container:

[image]

And this keeps going on forever. In the deployment logs of the service, it shows this:
[image]

I have no clue why this is happening. Shopify seem to not make deployment as straight forward as you'd like. From all this, my thoughts are that the undefined shop parameter is causing the health checks to fail, but have no clue how to combat this.

I have tried various different checks and ports and nothing seems to be working. I am not a pro at AWS so my knowledge isat a basic level. I hope that I have gievn enough information for someone to help guide/direct me in the right direction to help solve this issue, as it has been driving me crazy just to deploy this application. Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the `/plus-health-check` path you have configured the target group to use? Where did you get that path from? Did you actually add that as a health check endpoint like is described here? https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-cli-and-tools/how-to-add-health-check-endpoint-for-global-load-balancing/td-p/1842698

Comment: @MarkB This turned out to be the issue. But now it comes up with a 504 gateway error which I have no clue why its coming up